# How can I use accumulate like reduce2 function in purrr?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I would like to use the `accumulate` function with two input vectors and the `reduce2` function. The documentation for `accumulate` implies that two input vectors can be given and that `accumulate` can work with `reduce2`. However, I am having trouble.

Here is an example, inspired by the documentation from `reduce2`.

This is the example from `reduce2`

```
> paste2 <- function(x, y, sep = ".") paste(x, y, sep = sep)
> letters[1:4] %>% reduce2(.y=c("-", ".", "-"), paste2)
[1] "a-b.c-d"
```

Here are several attempts to use `accumulate` similarly to `reduce2`. None properly iterate through both `letters[1:4]` and `c("-",".","-")`.

```
> letters[1:4] %>% accumulate(.y=c("-", ".", "-"),paste2)
Error in .f(x, y, ...) : unused argument (.y = c("-", ".", "-"))

> letters[1:4] %>% accumulate(c("-", ".", "-"),paste2)
[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
NULL

> letters[1:4] %>% accumulate(sep=c("-", ".", "-"),paste2)
[1] "a"       "a-b"     "a-b-c"   "a-b-c-d"
```

How would I use `accumulate` to see the intermediate results given by the `reduce2` example?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that this is an oversight where the documentation is simply not up to date/a bit misleading? I could not get `accumulate` to accept a three argument function either, and I'm surprised there's no error in your last example though I guess it would have to be `paste` that throws it. The fact that the text for `.f` is exactly the same for `accumulate` as for `reduce` makes me think that this just isn't functionality present in `accumulate`. Additionally, looking at the source seems to show (unless I misread) that `reduce` and `reduce2` have their own implementation but `accumulate` relies on `base::Reduce`. Might be worth a GitHub issue.

Here's my best shot at producing the output you wanted. It basically involves calling `reduce2` multiple times with the right subset of the input list and the secondary input vector to `paste2`, which doesn't feel very neat or tidy. This might just not be a particularly neat or tidy problem. Note the use of the `{}` to override the default `%>%` behaviour of placing the pipe LHS as the first argument, and the different indexing on `.x` and `.y` inside `reduce2` (we want to keep `.y` one element shorter than `.x`).

```r
paste2 <- function(x, y, sep = ".") paste(x, y, sep = sep)

library(purrr)
letters[1:4] %>%
  {map_chr(
    .x = 2:length(.),
    .f = function(index) reduce2(
      .x = .[1:index],
      .y = c("-", ".", "-")[1:(index - 1)],
      .f = paste2
    )
  )}
#> [1] "a-b"     "a-b.c"   "a-b.c-d"
```

Created on 2018-05-11 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

A few months [after](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/commit/2b07c4152ac7e91f95dc086841854d40d48f4766) this post `accumulate2` was introduced that gives the results OP was after:

```r
library(purrr)

paste2 <- function(x, y, sep = ".") paste(x, y, sep = sep)
accumulate2(letters[1:4], c("-", ".", "-"), paste2)

#> [[1]]
#> [1] "a"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "a-b"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "a-b.c"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "a-b.c-d"
```

Answer (score 0):

With this trick you can use unlimited arguments in `accumulate` and you did not even need `accumulate2`

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- letters[1:4]
y <- c('-', '.', '-')

accumulate(seq_along(x[-1]), .init = x[1], ~paste(.x, x[.y+1], sep = y[.y]))
#> [1] "a"       "a-b"     "a-b.c"   "a-b.c-d"

# OR

accumulate(seq_along(y), .init = x[1], ~paste(.x, x[.y+1], sep = y[.y]))
#> [1] "a"       "a-b"     "a-b.c"   "a-b.c-d"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>