# Weird behavior with 3-argument purrr::accumulate?

Tags: r, purrr

This may/may not be a duplicate of [How can I use accumulate like reduce2 function in purrr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50295836/how-can-i-use-accumulate-like-reduce2-function-in-purrr) but I couldn't really understand the case being discussed there so asking this again.

I am trying to understand the working of `purrr::accummulate` especially when passing 3 arguments. Here's documentation for it -

> .x - A list or atomic vector.
>
> .f - For reduce(), a 2-argument function.
>   The function will be passed the accumulated value as the first
>   argument and the "next" value as the second argument. For reduce2(), a
>   3-argument function. The function will be passed the accumulated value
>   as the first argument, the next value of .x as the second argument,
>   and the **next value of .y as the third argument**.

Based on above documentation -

```
library(purrr)

# 2-argument use is pretty straightforward
accumulate(.x = 1:3, .f = sum)
[1] 1 3 6 # 1, 1+2, 1+2+3

# 3-argument result seems weird
accumulate(.x = 1:3, .y = 1:2, .f = sum)
[1]  1  6 12 # seems like 1, 1+2+3, 1+2+3+3+3
# expecting 1 4 9 i.e. 1, 1+2+1, 1+2+1+3+2

# reduce2 works correctly and gives 9
reduce2(.x = 1:3, .y = 1:2, .f = sum)
[1] 9

# it seems to take sum(y) as third argument instead of "next value of .y"
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: That description is for `reduce2`, but there is no `accumulate2()` function. There is no three argument version of `acculultate()`. Those `.y` values are just being passed though the `...` in the function signature. What is the output you expect?

Comment: It's possible that answer is right about the documentation being misleading. Why is it in there if it doesn't apply? It reads like it's suggestive of being used within `.f`. Another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52130992/cumulative-multiplication-in-r-with-the-addition-of-extra-constants) answer lists it as an [open issue from June 2018](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/511).

Comment: @MrFlick...I have added expected output and output for `reduce2`. I think your comment makes sense although in that case the documentation for `accumulate` is certainly wrong.

Comment: @Anonymouscoward Thanks for the info. I think it all makes sense now.